# Searching array for letters case insensitive in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am an absolute newbie to ActionScript 3 and I need to create a function that searches an array of alphabets for a specific letter and return its index. I already found the `indexOf` which is perfect. But I need this search to be not case sensitive. Like if my array is this:

```
Array("a","B","c")
```

if I am looking for `"A"` the index returned would be `0`.
Is there some predefined function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a predefined function for this.

You can write your own, though. Use a for-loop and iterate through the array, using [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#toLowerCase()) to alter both the array value and the check value temporarily for checking.

Actually... asking you to write your own is asking you to shoot yourself in the foot for something like this. Create a class `ArrayUtils`, stuff this function in it.

```
/**
* Searches through an array for a case-insensitive string match.
* Attempts to imitate Array.indexOf where it can.
* @param arr The array to search through
* @param searchingFor The string to search for
* @param fromIndex Optional, an index to start searching at.
* @returns The index of the array that a match was found at (zero-indexed), or -1 if no match was found.
*/
public static function indexOfCaseInsensitiveString(arr:Array, searchingFor:String, fromIndex:uint = 0):int {
    var lowercaseSearchString:String = searchingFor.toLowerCase();
    var arrayLength:uint = arr.length;//Retrieving array length is expensive, optimization
    for(var index:uint = fromIndex; index < arrayLength; index++){
        var element:* = arr[index];
        if(element is String && element.toLowerCase() == lowercaseSearchString){
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;//It wasn't found in the array.
}
```

You could then call it via `ArrayUtils.indexOfCaseInsensitiveString(<your array>, <your string>)`. The `fromIndex` is just there to mimic the regular `indexOf` (principle of least surprise; if I say it's "`indexOf` with case-insensitive string search", why would that affect `fromIndex`?).

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I havn't compiled this code, this is just to demonstrate how I would go about it.
you should check nulls and non-string variables. you should use Vector.<String> instead of Array

nope, there is none.

the simplest way:

```
    function getCaseInsensitiveIndexOf(needle:String, haystack:Array):int
    {
        var index:int = -1;
        if(needle != null)
        {
            index = haystack.indexOf(needle.toUpperCase());
            if(index == -1)
                index = haystack.indexOf(needle.toLowerCase());
        }
        return index;
    }
```

// bellow is my first answer, but its overkill

you have to normalize the content of the array beforehand.
you possibly want to normalize a copy of it actually, so you don't loose any detail.

```
    function getNormalizedVersionOf(target:Array):Array
    {
        var copy:Array = [];
        for(var i:int = 0; i < target.length; i++)
        {
            copy[i] = (target[i] as String).toUpperCase();  // or .toLowerCase()
        }
        return copy;
    }
```

and when you search, you search on the normalized copy

```
    function getItemIndex(searchFor:String):int
    {
        var s:String = searchFor.toUpperCase();
        return mNormalized.indexOf(s);  //if you have the copy array as a class member called mNormalized
    }
```

Comment: This is dangerous: you cast to string without checking anything - arrays will be cast to string too and you can get get matches in sub arrays. It's also O(2n), which is slow. Lastly, it has compile errors. `targetArray` is undefined. The compile errors warrant a -1.

Comment: @Pimgd its not intended to use in production, since we know very little about how it would be used, anyone how paste this into an editor would immediately see the compile error, which is a simple rename problem... so down voting it because of that is pure spite.
vote it down because of the unnecessary normalization, if you must :) which is a good point

Comment: Don't post code that's not production ready without a disclaimer. People will come and copy paste the darn things... so it's best if it's documented and doesn't blow up in their face. I upvoted your answer because you make a good point; they should use a Vector instead of an Array. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular Expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) may be used to achieve this using the case insensitive flag.

```
function findTargetIndex(needle:String,heystack:Array):int
{
    var straw:String;
    var magnet:RegExp = new RegExp(needle,"i");//"i" flag makes the search case insensitive.
    //can also be done with magnet.ignoreCase = true;
    for (var x:int = 0; x < heystack.length; x++)
    {
        straw = heystack[x];
        if (straw.search(magnet) > -1) return x;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The above function would search the array looking for any element that contains your search string. You can limit it to matching whole strings only by altering the RegExp;

```
var magnet:RegExp = new RegExp("^"+needle+"$","i");
```

`^` matches the beginning of a string, `$` matches the end, meaning the whole string must match the whole expression.